# SUM Value Based On Day Near Each Other By A Day

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

So, I wanted to get the SUM of `New Ink (ml)` and `Ink Used (ml)` grouped by `Date`, `Paper Code`, and `Ink Code` but I also wanted the `Date` group the difference of the `Date` only by a day

Main Table

| Date | Paper Code | Ink Code | New Ink (ml) | Ink Used (ml) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-1-2022 | 911 | C21 | 10 | 8 |
| 10-1-2022 | 911 | C29 | 9 | 3 |
| 10-2-2022 | 911 | C21 | 8 | 3 |
| 10-5-2022 | 911 | C21 | 25 | 15 |
| 10-12-2022 | 911 | C21 | 10 | 8 |
| 10-13-2022 | 911 | C21 | 8 | 6 |
| 10-15-2022 | 911 | C21 | 6 | 6 |
| 10-15-2022 | 911 | C29 | 9 | 9 |

Expected result should be :

For `Date` 10-1-2022 and 10-2-2022

| Paper Code | Ink Code | New Ink (ml) | Ink Used (ml) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 911 | C21 | 18 | 11 |
| 911 | C29 | 9 | 3 |

For `Date` 10-5-2022

| Paper Code | Ink Code | New Ink (ml) | Ink Used (ml) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 911 | C21 | 25 | 15 |

For `Date` 10-12-2022 and 10-13-2022

| Paper Code | Ink Code | New Ink (ml) | Ink Used (ml) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 911 | C21 | 18 | 14 |

For `Date` 10-15-2022

| Paper Code | Ink Code | New Ink (ml) | Ink Used (ml) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 911 | C21 | 6 | 6 |
| 911 | C29 | 9 | 9 |

and all combined would be

| Paper Code | Ink Code | New Ink (ml) | Ink Used (ml) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 911 | C21 | 18 | 11 |
| 911 | C29 | 9 | 3 |
| 911 | C21 | 25 | 15 |
| 911 | C21 | 18 | 14 |
| 911 | C21 | 6 | 6 |
| 911 | C29 | 9 | 9 |

I've tried

```
SELECT 
    [Paper Code],
    [Ink Code],
    SUM([New Ink (ml)]) AS [New Ink (ml)],
    SUM([Ink Used (ml)]) AS [Ink Used (ml)]
FROM [Table Ink]
GROUP BY [Paper Code], [Ink Code]
```

Comment: I trying to get it.
You want to sum up two days by combining (1,2), (3,4), (5,6) ... right ?
What I don't understand in your example is the aggregation for 10-12-2022 and 10-13-2022 where it should result in 18(new Ink)  and 14 (ink used). 
Could you please check ?

Comment: @AndiKleinbichler Oops, fixed! I just copy pasted that and forgot to change the value, thank you! To be more specific with the combined two days is that, the days only has to be next to each other, like 11-12, 8-9, 13-14. And in this database there won't be days like 3-4-5 but more like 3-4 and then 6-7.

Comment: You could use some window functions Lag/Leap for that purpose (https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-lag-function-overview-and-examples/). It can combine fields from previous and current records values from from a partition. In the select part of the statement you can than build proper sums.
But please take care of performance. For large tables this would not scale well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you can use `LAG()` or `LEAD()` to identify the group of rows. After that just use `GROUP BY` as per normal

```
with cte as
(
  select *,
         g = case when datediff(day, lag([Date]) over (order by [Date]),
                                     [Date]) > 1
                  then 1
                  else 0
                  end
  from   [Table Ink]
),
cte2 as
(
  select *, grp = sum(g) over (order by [Date])
  from   cte
)
select [Paper Code],  [Ink Code],
       sum([New Ink (ml)])  as [New Ink (ml)],
       sum([Ink Used (ml)]) as [Ink Used (ml)]
from   cte2
group by grp, [Paper Code],  [Ink Code]
```